# Got TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'dim_order' when calculating Temperature advection with Metpy?

Tags: python, typeerror, metpy

I was recreating the code from [**Metpy Case Study**](https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/MetPy_Case_Study/metpy-case-study/?fbclid=IwAR0grZ4saWmkUF7B15damoyRm36vG83pbRZzpmXaLK_1ZdGw71r1mfefEhI#Calculations:)

using ERA5 data. But calculating advection I got this error:
 `TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'dim_order'`

[image: Code]

Here is my full code using colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UlYPoT6rF7BkHCIta8t7DlnTeq8Mu8wr?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

The linked example is unfortunately out-of-date with recent versions of MetPy. As noted in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68504772/10714117), the signature for `metpy.calc.advection` as of v1.0 has changed to [`(scalar, u, v)`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.advection.html), and `dim_order` is no longer valid as an argument, but instead dimension order is automatically inferred (or manually specified with `y_dim` and `x_dim`). In your example, using the updated API could look something like

```py
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.units import units
import xarray as xr

data = xr.open_dataset(file).metpy.parse_cf()

level = 850 * units.hPa  # units.Quantity([ 250,  300,  500,  750,  850,
                         # 925, 1000], 'hPa')

temp = data['t'].isel(time=0).metpy.sel(vertical=level)
u_wind = data['u'].isel(time=0).metpy.sel(vertical=level)
v_wind = data['v'].isel(time=0).metpy.sel(vertical=level)

temp_adv = mpcalc.advection(temp, u_wind, v_wind)
```